# Ubuntu reinstall apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, package-management

Apache has been corrupted somehow and now it just displays the following error when going to any page.

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

This is nothing to do with .htaccess, everything was working fine on multiple virtual hosts before my virtual machine screwed up some files.

I think the best idea is to reinstall the apache2 package.

I have tried `apt-get --purge remove apache2` and `apt-get --reinstall install apache2`. Nothing seems to work, it just marks it as removed but doesn't actually remove the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-get remove apache2`

`mv /etc/apache /etc/apache.old`

`apt-get install apache2`

Comment: 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/1,484B of archives.
After this operation, 36.9kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously deselected package apache2....  Looks like it just uses the old package.

Comment: Does it happily install a new /etc/apache ?

Comment: I think I finally fixed it with `sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common libapache2-mod-php5`